# createPortal does not overwrite div contents (like ReactDOM.render)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get `ReactDOM.createPortal` to override the contents of the container I am mounting it too. However it seems to appendChild.

Is it possible to override contents? Similar to `ReactDOM.render`?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

class PrivacyContent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return createPortal(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Click me
                </button>
            </div>,
            document.getElementById('privacy')
        )
    }

    handleClick() {
        alert('clicked');
    }

}

export default PrivacyContent;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor of the component, you could actually clear the contents of the div before rendering your Portal content:

```
class PrivacyContent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const myNode = document.getElementById("privacy");
        while (myNode.firstChild) {
            myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
        }
    }
    render() {
        return createPortal(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Click me
                </button>
            </div>,
            document.getElementById('privacy')
        )
    }

    handleClick() {
        alert('clicked');
    }

}

export default PrivacyContent;
```

Comment: Thank you Shubham this is what I'm doing however I feel it's a workaround. Does how come `ReactDOM.render` behaves differently?

Comment: ReactDOM.render, does replace the content, you could use it too in your component and return null from within render `https://codesandbox.io/s/x72nz4m21z. However I am not sure about whether to use this pattern instead of createPortal or not.

Comment: Thank you @Subham I'll just use the remove first node technique.

Comment: Glad to have helped

Answer (score 5):

If you know what you're doing, here is a `<Portal />` component that under the hoods creates a portal, empties the target DOM node and mounts any component with any props:

```
const Portal = ({ Component, container, ...props }) => {
  const [innerHtmlEmptied, setInnerHtmlEmptied] = React.useState(false)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!innerHtmlEmptied) {
      container.innerHTML = ''
      setInnerHtmlEmptied(true)
    }
  }, [innerHtmlEmptied])
  if (!innerHtmlEmptied) return null
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(<Component {...props} />, container)
}
```

Usage:

```
<Portal Component={MyComponent} container={document.body} {...otherProps} />
```

This empties the content of `document.body`, then mounts `MyComponent` while passing down `otherProps`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: man, that helps a lot when trying to run tests with jest. I fought 8h until I found your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Bit of an old question, but here's another sync solution (without useState). Also in a reusable component format.

```js
const Portal = ({ selector, children, replaceContent = true }) => {
  const target = useRef(document.querySelector(selector)).current;
  const hasMounted = useRef(false);

  if (!target) return null;
  if (replaceContent && !hasMounted.current) {
    target.innerHTML = '';
    hasMounted.current = true;
  }

  return createPortal(children, target);
};
```

Comment: This is safer for React 18 dev mode as well which runs `useEffect` twice, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I find this is better and doesn't need useState:

```
  export const Portal = () => {
  const el = useRef(document.createElement('div'));

  useEffect(() => {
    const current = el.current;
    // We assume `root` exists with '?'
    if (!root?.hasChildNodes()) {
      root?.appendChild(current);
    }

    return () => void root?.removeChild(current);
  }, []);

  return createPortal(<Cmp />, el.current);
};
```

Comment: What does `root` reference here? is it supposed to be `current`?

Answer (score 1):

A solution with zero hook dependencies

```js
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

const getNode = (id) => {
  const domNode = document.getElementById(id);
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  domNode?.replaceChildren(div);
  return div;
};

const Portal = ({ children }) => {
  const domNode = getNode("privacy");
  if (domNode) {
    return createPortal(children, domNode);
  }
  return null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM API ,such as `removeChild` to remove DOM Node may cause error like this:

[React DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880669/react-domexception-failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node-the-node-to-be-re)

So ,at last, I use ReactDOM.render to get it .

```
ReactDOM.render(<div/>, node);
```