# React DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If state is true to play youtube video, and it is false I would like to delete youtube playing. 
MY code is as follows.

```
{this.state.isPreViewVideo && <PlayYouTube video_id="ScSn235gQx0" />}
```

sandbox URL:

https://codesandbox.io/s/xryoz10k6o

Reproduction method:

If 4-digit characters are included in input form, "isPreViewVideo: true" by setState  and if it is less than false

It works fine when state is true,
but when state is false, I encounter this error as follows.

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

is there a way to avoid or resolve this error?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This error, `Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node`, can also be raised if Google Translate is used (or any other plugin that changes the page DOM).

This is detailed in this Github issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11538

Answer (score 58):

In playYouTube.tsx line 78 replace `<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>` 
with `<div>...</div>`

> Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes
>   to the DOM.

This explains the error 
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

More on fragments here https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Could you you explain why does this happen more in detail, please? Why does it throw the error when using `React.Fragment` and not when using `div`?

Comment: Yes, why does this happen? If this happens without any foreseeable reason, then should we stop using fragments??

Comment: Because Fragments dosen't add anything to the DOM. See this Codepen created by React team https://codepen.io/reactjs/pen/VrEbjE?editors=1000
The Fragments(<></>) are not added to the DOM. 

The Code-sandbox created by @sukho has been changed now but in the original Code-sandbox there where Fragments wrapping the video player. Also if I remember correctly there was a method for removing the video player. The parent element of the video-player would try remove every child element and since the parent element were Fragments this would fail since there were no parent-child relationship

Comment: This answer helped me navigate to my specific issue. In my case this error happened when I render/return `<i className="fa-circle"/>` alone. This code fix this:  `<span><i className="fa-circle"/></span>`.

Comment: @mojmir.novak 's comment was very helpful to me as it solves the issue. Can you tell me the reason why it works with <span/> but not for <i/>?

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca I am not sure. It looks like a bug or maybe javaScript manipulation by font awesome, but I had no time to analyze that.

Comment: In my case I had a jQuery based modal in the DOM (fomantic-ui / semantic-ui), and it was wrapped in a Fragment. Just making `<>` a `<div>` resolved it. wtf, I spent more than an hour trying to resolve this!

Comment: The exact same thing happed to me. I was using <></> Fragment syntax.

Answer (score 21):

**Problem explanation:**

When `isPreViewVideo` is truthy, you have this:

```
<PlayYouTube video_id="ScSn235gQx0" />
```

That probably renders to something like this:

```
<div> <!-- the root element as rendered by PlayYouTube if isPreViewVideo is truthy -->
  <embed /> <!-- the video player or whatever PlayYouTube renders -->
</div>
```

Now if some code removes the player by directly manipulating the DOM and removing the root `div`, you'll end up with... Well, with nothing.

But in React's virtual DOM, the root `div` still exists! So when `isPreViewVideo` goes falsy, React tries to remove it from the real DOM but since it's already gone, the error is thrown.

**The solution:**

To expand on @henrik123's answer - wrapping `PlayYouTube` with a `div` like this...

```
<div> <!-- the root element rendered if isPreViewVideo is truthy -->
  <PlayYouTube video_id="ScSn235gQx0" />
</div>
```

...causes this to render:

```
<div> <!-- the root element rendered if isPreViewVideo is truthy -->
  <div> <!-- the element as rendered by PlayYouTube -->
    <embed /> <!-- the video player or whatever PlayYouTube renders -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the same code that removes the player by removing its root `div` makes it look like this:

```
<div> <!-- the root element rendered if isPreViewVideo is truthy -->
</div>
```

Now when `isPreViewVideo` goes falsy, the root exists both in React's virtual DOM and in the real DOM so there is no problem in removing it. It's children have changed but React doesn't care in this case - it just needs to remove the root.

**Note:**

Other HTML elements but `div` may work too.

**Note 2:**

Wrapping with `React.Fragment` instead of a `div` would not work because `React.Fragment` doesn't add anything to the real DOM. So with this...

```
<React.Fragment>
  <PlayYouTube video_id="ScSn235gQx0" />
</React.Fragment>
```

...you still end up with this:

```
<div> <!-- the root element as rendered by PlayYouTube if isPreViewVideo is truthy -->
  <embed /> <!-- the video player or whatever PlayYouTube renders -->
</div>
```

And you have the same issue.

**TL;DR solution:**

Wrap `PlayYouTube` with a `div`.

Comment: For me your solution combined with wrapping all code inside return with `<></>` instead of div resolved issue. +1

Answer (score 9):

> SOLVED for bootstrap alert after manually close button

I had exact error when i close the bootstrap alert error message if it's there manually and then submit the form again. what i had done is to wrap up the AlertError component with extra  tag around.

```js
import React from "react";

const AlertError = (props) => {
    return (
        <div> // <---- Added this
            <div className="alert alert-custom alert-notice alert-light-danger fade show" role="alert">
                <div className="alert-icon"><i className="flaticon-warning"></i></div>
                <div className="alert-text">There is an error in the form..!</div>
                <div className="alert-close">
                    <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true"><i className="ki ki-close"></i></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> // <---- Added this
    );
};

export default AlertError;
```

Comment: This was exactly in my case too! Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This error can occur when you use external JS or jQuery plugins. Let me tell about my case.

### Issue description

In my React project I have some links on a page, every link opens a modal with some info and a slider with images inside it. Every link has its own set of images inside the slider. But I have the single modal, it is the same for every link.
Data for modal is stored in a state variable and I change its content on every link click (on every modal open):

```
const initialData = { title: "", intro: "" }; // here is some empty structure of object properties, we need it for the modalResponse initialization
const [modalData, setModalData] = useState(initialData);
// ...
<div id="MyModal">
    <div className="title">{modalData.title}</div>
    <div className="intro">{modalData.intro}</div>
    <div>{modalData.sliderHtml}</div>
</div>
```

When I open modal using `setModalData()` I fill `modalData` with some new data. HTML-code inside `modalData.sliderHtml` is something like this structure:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="first.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="second.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="third.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

When modal has opened I call some jQuery code for slider initialization:

```
useEffect(() => {
    $('.carousel').initCarousel({
        // some options
    });
}, [modalData]);
```

Then user could close the modal and click the next link. The slider must be filled by new set of images. But I get the error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

### Error reason

**The reason of the issue is in a fact that the jQuery plugin changes the structure of html during initialization.** It creates some new blocks inside the `.carousel` parent (arrows to the left/right, dots for navigation, etc.). And it moves all the `.item` children inside the new `.items` block! I get such html structure after the plugin initialization:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="dots">...</div>
    <div class="arrows">...</div>
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item"><img src="first.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="second.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="third.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When React tries to change the content of `modalData.sliderHtml` it executes some magic DOM operations for old structure removing. One of this operations is `removeChild` method, but the old `.item` elements can't be found inside the parent `.carousel` because the plugin moved them inside the new `.items` element. So, we get the error.

### Bug fixing

I started to change `modalData` content back to the initialData structure every time when the modal is closed.

```
useEffect(() => {
    $('#MyModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        setModalData(initialData);
    })
}, []);
```

So, all html structure inside `modalData.sliderHtml` is filled by the initial empty data again and we don't get an error on the new link click.

Answer (score 5):

### Most probable cause: something modified the DOM after React

The most probable cause of this issue is that something other than React modified the DOM after React rendered to it.

### What's causing this DOM mutation?

Depending on the profile of users who are impacted, there might be a few different causes.

#### Everyone

If all your users are impacted, you, the developer might be the culprit.

The cause is probably that you are using jQuery or doing DOM manipulations outside of React.

#### Usual users

If usual users are affected, the most probable cause is Google Chrome translate feature (or [Microsoft translate](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-microsoft-translator-in-microsoft-edge-browser-4ad1c6cb-01a4-4227-be9d-a81e127fcb0b) on Edge Chromium).

Thankfully there's an easy solution for that: add a `<meta>` tag in your HTML `<head>` ([Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2008/10/helping-you-break-language-barrier)).

```html
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
```

This should also disable Microsoft Translator on Edge Chromium.

#### Advanced users

If only advanced users are affected, and they are not using a translation feature on their browser, then it might be a browser extension or some userscript (most likely run by SpiderMonkey) that causes the problem.

### More info

- [Issue on React repo](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11538)
- SolidJS is also [affected](https://github.com/solidjs/solid/issues/1451)
- [Issue on Chromium bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=872770) (please star it to help prioritize it)

Answer (score 3):

I had same problems with a audio tag and I kept this tag within two nested div and now its working

Answer (score 2):

This is a very annoying bug to fix. But you should wrap the component that you are rendering it conditionally with `span` element.

Check this GitHub issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11538#issuecomment-390386520

Answer (score 0):

In one place of our code was something like this:

```
render() {
 if (el) return <div />

 return '';
}
```

After replacing ' ' with null, all works without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with react. The problem was caused by a google-auth script tag in index.html.

`<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>`

This is while I had another on the JS file causing the issue. Be sure to check for conflicting or repeated CDNs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just needed to reset the state OR make it to initial data when I needed to render it with new data. It fixed  the issue.

Ex:
This issue occurred when I was setting table data upon getting API response in useFetch. Before setting the data to state, I first set it to initial value.
setTableData([]);
setTableData(data.response);

I hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this error too，because I use `React.createPortal` and want to  override the contents of the container. like this:

```
  const node = document.getElementById('middle-bottom-panel');
  useMemo(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unmodified-loop-condition
    while (node && node.firstChild) {
      node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
  }, []);
```

At last I give up `removeChild`, and use `ReactDOM.render`, thing seems become all right.

```
ReactDOM.render(<div/>, node);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue occurred when using `React.forwardRef`. My code snippet looked like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  const VideoPlayer = React.forwardRef(({source}, ref) => {
    return (
      <video ref={ref} id='player' src={source}/>
    )
  })

  return (
    <VideoPlayer source='https://link.to.video' ref={ref}/>
  )
)}
```

Every time React state changed, and `VideoPlayer` re-rendered, it would throw the following error:

> Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

[image: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.]

### Solution

All I had to was wrap my `<video>` tag in a `div`, like this:

```js
const VideoPlayer = React.forwardRef(({source}, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={ref} id='player' src={source}/>
    </div>
  )
})
```

As others have mentioned, using `React.Fragement` or `<>` would not work, as it added nothing to the DOM.

Answer (score -2):

- [Node.removeChild() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

fix:

```js
   unmountContainer() {
      // macro task
      setTimeout(() => {
        // refs
        if (containerEle) {
          // receive removed node
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
          let removedChild = document
            .querySelector('.page__wrapper')
            .removeChild(containerEle);
        }
      });
    }
```